# how to insert hindi data in mysql from excel file using php(codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

i am developing a php application that store some value in database in hindi font using excel file.

i want to import hindi text excel file in mysql database. but when i import excel file in mysql using php script hindi characters are change in english chars and stored in database.
so please help me how to insert hindi text in database using excel file

like i want to insert पृथ्वी के आन्तरिक भाग में तापक्रम वितरण सि संबंधित सत्य कथन है
but instead i got output i`Foh ds vkUrfjd Hkkx esa rki?e forj.k ls lacaf/kr lR; dFku g

plz help me

Answer (score 0):

what is the encoding of the field you want to insert Hindi character?
if it is not UTF-8 change it the encoding to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

- Choose utf8 character set and utf8_general_ci collation

For example

```
  ALTER TABLE `<table_name>` CHANGE `<field_name>` `<field_name>` VARCHAR(150) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT '' NOT NULL;
```

- Once you've connected to database, run the following statement at first

  ```
  mysql_set_charset('utf8');
  ```
- Before you printing any unicode text (say Hindi,Gujrati or any other text) on browser, you should have to set content type of that page by adding a meta tag

  ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  ```

Comment: when i type text in to excel using google input tool in hindi language, the typed text are automatically converted in to unicode. and then i import excel file  it is successfully inserted hindi text in db. but when i create a excel file using hindi font and import it then inserted text look like this i`Foh ds vkUrfjd Hkkx esa rki?e

Comment: its actually problem with utf and check the version of utf in excel as well as database.

Comment: which version of office you are use ?(like openOffice or office 2003/8/10/13)

Comment: i use ms office 2010 and i try it on office 2013

Comment: if possible then you must change the import petters like you are import excel file then you import in CSV file

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are using a proprietary hindi font and not unicode in your excel.  What is the font that you see in excel when you are on the cell with the hindi text? Alternatively you can copy the the text from the cell in excel and paste it in notepad.  If you continue to see the hindi then it is unicode but if you see the exact same string you see in the mysql table, that is more or less conclusive that you are using a proprietary font.

If you are using a proprietary font, you have to perform an intermediate step of converting from the proprietary encoding to unicode encoding.  I have a [project on github](https://github.com/kinjal/custom2unicode) for doing this, feel free to read through it, figure out the logic and implement it in the language of your choice.